# Anychart create graph using function as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, anychart

I have this function with which I create AnyChart Graph. I want to make a lot of functions, for different graphs, like this one, and also to show them into different MaterialDialogs.

```kotlin
        private fun createChart(): Cartesian {
            val cartesian: Cartesian = AnyChart.cartesian(
            (...)
            return cartesian
        }
```

For this task, I made a general function, which will be called with the specific views IDs and specific function for creating the graph

```kotlin
private fun showDialog(layoutId : Int , chartId : Int, function: (Chart)) {

        val dialog = MaterialDialog(requireContext())
            .customView(layoutId)
            .cornerRadius(5.5f)

        val chartView: AnyChartView = dialog.findViewById(chartId)
        APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(chartView)
        chartView.setDebug(true)

        chartView.setChart(function) // <------ The problem is here
        //chartView.setChart(createChart() works fine 
        dialog.show()
    }
```

I will call this function at onClick listener of some view and specify which chart to be shown and which draw function to be used

```kotlin
private fun showWeatherDialog() {
        showDialog(R.layout.activity_graph_test,R.id.any_chart_view,createChart())
}
```

If I use the normal function call, the graph is drawn normally, but when I call the function  parameter it doesn't work

> ```kotlin
>    chartView.setChart(function) // <------ The problem is here
>    //chartView.setChart(createChart() works fine
> ```

The error from Anychart:

> E/AnyChart: Uncaught ReferenceError: cartesian43 is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```kotlin
    private fun showWeatherDialog() {
        showDialog(R.layout.activity_graph_test, R.id.any_chart_view) { createChart() }
    }

    private fun showDialog(layoutId: Int, chartId: Int, drawingChart: (()-> Cartesian)) {
         (...)
        chartView.setChart(drawingChart.invoke())
        dialog.show()
    }
```